# how to align a image to cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

i need to align an image to a cell using openpyxl, but this dont give any error but it doesnt align to the right of the cell.

```
        ws.merge_cells('A1:H1')
        ws['A1'].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="7FFFD4", fill_type="solid")
        # set the height of the row
        ws.row_dimensions[1].height = 150
        # set the width of the column
        ws.column_dimensions['B'].width = 40
        img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('img/Imagem1.png')
        img.anchor = 'A1'
        ws.add_image(img)
        ws['A1'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='right')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem occurs because you add the styling *AFTER* you fill the cell with data. Openpyxl can only add styling *BEFORE* there is data in the cell.

I made two small example scripts below to better explain. In the first script I add the styling after the cell is filled and in the second script I add the styling before the cell is filled.

Script 1:

```
# In the script below I add the styling before the cell is filled with data
# This way the data in cell A1 becomes red

from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

selected_cell = ws['A1']
selected_cell.font = Font(color="00FF0000")
ws['A1'].value = "Example data"

wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

Script 2:

```
# In the script below I add the styling after the cell is filled with data
# This way the data in cell B1 doesn't become red

from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws['B1'].value = "Exmaple data"
selected_cell = ws['A1']
selected_cell.font = Font(color="00FF0000")

wb.save("test.xlsx")
```